# Return "1" or "2" for Empty cells depending on value in a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking for a DAX function for empty cells in the "Name" Column that should return "1" in result column if the previous value in "Name" Column is not equal and if equal it should return "2" in the result column.

[image]

For Example, in the above table, row 3 in the Name Column is empty and row 2 in the Name column is "AA" and row 4 in Name Column is "BB" so it should return "1" in the result column. Because "AA" and "BB" are different.

Row 6 & 7 in the Name Column are also empty, but the Name Column value in row 5 and 8 are equal so it should return as "2" in row 6 & 7 in the result column.

Comment: so, you want to label the gaps with 1 if the value changes over the gap and 2 if the value stays the same over the gap?

Comment: @RyanB. Yes. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide some index in your table that defines order. In Excel, you have row numbers for that, but in Power BI there are no such numbers. The index can be Dates, or some numeric sequence that you assign to each record.

Comment: @RADO I have added an Index Column. Can you please explain to me how to write a function using the index column?.

Comment: I think, you should populate the "Result" column in the source itself. DAX functions generally aggregate data. There is no aggregation here. DAX also has row context aware functions, but here the row that you want to populate depends on values of other rows. So, it is best to populate "Result" column in the source like SQL Server or Access.